# Route and Router in React don't show the Components

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use Router from react-dom and it actually worked in the left tab in App.js but when I'm trying to do the same thing in dashboard.jsx , it only shows the first link which is "/dashboard"; On any branch of this link, it won't show any components; Like a complete blank page when I try to reach "/dashboard/shophistory";

I'll really apperciate it if anyone could help; TNX!

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/header';
import MainSection from './components/mainSection';
import SectionHeader from './components/sectionHeader';
import Statistic from './components/statistic';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
  } from "react-router-dom";
import Login from './components/login';
import Dashboard from './components/dashboard';
function App() {
    return ( 
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" className = "App">
                    <Header/>
                    <SectionHeader/>
                    <MainSection/>
                    <Statistic/>
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/login">
                    <Header/>
                    <Login/>
                </Route>
                <Route exact path="/dashboard">
                    <Header/>
                    <Dashboard/>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Dashboard.jsx (used component on App.js)

```
import React from "react";
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    Link
} from "react-router-dom";
import OverallCondition from "./dashOverall";
import Toolbar from "./dashToolbar";

export default function Dashboard(){
    return <section className='dashboard'>
        {/* ----------------- */}
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/dashboard/shophistory'>
                    <Toolbar/>
                    <h1>Shop</h1>
                </Route>
                <Route exact path='/dashboard/checkuphistory'>
                    <Toolbar/>
                    <h1>Check up</h1>
                </Route>
                <Route exact path='/dashboard'>
                    <Toolbar/>
                    <OverallCondition/>
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
        {/* -------------------- */}
    </section>
}
```

Toolbar.jsx (used component on Dashboard.jsx)

```
import React from "react";
export default function Toolbar(){
    return <div className="toolbar">
    <a href="/dashboard"><div>Overall Condition</div></a>
    <a href="/dashboard/shophistory"><div>Shopping History</div></a>
    <a href=""><div>Check Up History</div></a>
    <a href=""><div>Microchip Data</div></a>
    <a href=""><div>Vaccinations</div></a>
    <a href=""><div>Tests</div></a>
    </div>
}
```

Overallcondition.jsx (used component on Dashboard.jsx)

```
import React from 'react';
import calendar from '../img/calendar.png';
export default function OverallCondition(){
    return <div className="personalData">
    <h1 className="page">
        Overall Condition
    </h1>
    <div className="row">
        <div className="profile">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Image of Animal" />
            <div className="details">
                <h1 className="name">
                    Vito - Schpitz
                </h1>
                <small>
                    3 years old - Mainly Brown - Microchip code : ########
                </small>
                <h3 className="owner">
                    <span className="name">
                         Owner : Enzo Marian - #######
                    </span> <br />
                    <span className="number">
                        phone-number : ###########
                    </span>
                </h3>
                <p className="address">
                    <strong>Address :</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur <br /> adipisicing elit. Quaerat similique alias a soluta? Impedit, eligendi nostrum rem corrupti ut beatae.
                </p>
            </div>
            <img src={calendar} alt="calendar" className="calendar" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="gallery">
        <span>{'<'}</span>
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Image of Animal" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Image of Animal" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Image of Animal" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Image of Animal" />
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/150" alt="Image of Animal" />
        <span>{'>'}</span>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Please paste the code into your question. This makes it easier for us to read, as well as to copy-paste parts we'd like to highlight. Additionally, the service hosting your images could remove the images - making this question less useful to people in the future.

Comment: Yeah sure! Done...  So any thoughts on my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `exact` from your `/dashboard` route.

That `exact` will make sure that that route is only matched when the URL is exactly `/dashboard`.

`/dashboard/shophistory` does not match `/dashboard` exactly. So the route doesn't render your `<Dashboard />` component, which in turn does not render the routes defined in your `<Dashboard />` component.

Comment: well actually that `/dashboard` route works fine. I have problem with rendering the components on something like `/dashboard/checkup`. I thought it wouldn't be problem if we declare exact attribute in almost every route...

Comment: It depends, `exact` has its use cases. `exact` will indeed do fine most of the time as long as you don't nest routes inside the component rendered by an `exact` route. Which is the case in your scenario. Your `/dashboard/checkup` route doesn't work, because it is declared inside the `Dashboard` component rendered by `/dashboard`. `/dashboard/checkup` doesn't match `/dashboard` exactly. So `Dashboard` doesn't get rendered. Which in it's turn doesn't declare your `/dashboard/checkup` route. -> So you end up with a blank page.

Comment: Your `/dashboard` route works perfectly fine indeed. Because when you go to `/dashboard`. It matches the `/dashboard` route exactly, and renders your `Dashboard` component.